# deserializing an xml to c# object and serializing it in a different way

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Hi I have a Web Service that feeds my application with the following XML:

```
<Value><TABLE>
   <PRODUCT>
      <ProductID> 1 </ProductID>
      <Category> sport </Category>
      <Description> calcio </Description>
      <Name> palla </Name>
      <Price> 10 </Price>
   </PRODUCT>
   <PRODUCT>
      <ProductID> 2 </ProductID>
      <Category> sport </Category>
      <Description> tennis </Description>
      <Name> racchetta </Name>
      <Price> 100 </Price>
   </PRODUCT>
   <PRODUCT>
      <ProductID> 3 </ProductID>
      <Category> sport </Category>
      <Description> golf </Description>
      <Name> borsa </Name>
      <Price> 150 </Price>
   </PRODUCT>
</TABLE></Value>
```

I wrote the following object models and I manage to deserialize correcly using XmlSerializer.

```
[XmlRoot("Value")]
public class Value {
    [XmlElement("TABLE")]
    public TABLE TABLE { get; set; }
}

public class TABLE {
    [XmlElement("PRODUCT")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}


public class Product {
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; } 
}
```

Now, I eventually add new Product objects and I want to serialize the model into and XML in order to sending it back to the web service. The problem is that the XML structure accepted is slighty different, I'd want the XML structure to be like this:

```
<setProdotti>
<streams>
<instream>
<Value><TABLE>
       <PRODUCT>
          <ProductID> 1 </ProductID>
          <Category> sport </Category>
          <Description> calcio </Description>
          <Name> palla </Name>
          <Price> 10 </Price>
       </PRODUCT>
</TABLE></Value>
</instream>
</streams>
</setProdotti>
```

Basically the same as the input XML with the exception of the embedding tags setProdotti, streams and instream, which are fixed and known (can be hardcoded).
Can it be done with the current model? I tryed to use XmlSerializer's Serialize method but id output an XML based on the model (of course) and with tags on the root elements that I'd like to avoid too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<TABLE>
<PRODUCT><ProductID>1</ProductID><Name> palla </Name><Description> nike </Description><Category> calcio </Category><Price>10</Price></PRODUCT>
</TABLE>
</Value>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Easiest solution is to return the `Value` object nested inside three container classes with the necessary element names.  Is there a reason you can't do that?

Comment: You can manually create three elements around your xml using the `XmlWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of Alexander Petrov, I looked into detail the XmlWriter
The resulting code that satisfy my requirements is:

```
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            XmlSerializer xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Value));
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlWriter writer2 = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings {
                OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
            });
            writer2.WriteStartElement("setProdotti");
            writer2.WriteStartElement("streams");
            writer2.WriteStartElement("instream");
            xmlserializer.Serialize(writer2, p, ns);
            writer2.Dispose();
            string serializedXml = stringWriter.ToString();
```

The part about `XmlSerializerNamespaces`avoid the creation of XML attributes on the Value element (p) and i set up `XmlWriterSetting` so that I have no XML declaration at the beginning of the string.
Apparently `.Dispose()` closes the tags I opened with `.WriteStartElement`. I was looking for the `.Close()` method but it doesn't exist anymore.